# Why is my texture atlas dark and messed up?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have been messing with the texture atlas tool  a couple of times, and it has really helped me out and worked perfectly until today. When I tried baking the texture atlas, it didn't come out right. It is very dark and has some black spots that look like letters or numbers. Here is the product
[image: product]

and the image is as shown here
[image]

I made sure I selected all the objects I wanted to combine into a single image and that the combined object was the last/active one. I selected no unwrap because I had already dont that. My baking options are as follows:
[image: bake]

I was able to tell that it didn't bake all the objects right as some were cut off or lost their aspect ratio so to say. Any ideas?

Comment: Uncheck both Direct and Indirect in pass baking options, they are including shadow information which you don't want in diffuse map. For some objects cut off try increasing Ray Distance to something like 0.1 (in Blender units)

Comment: @MrZak thank you, the lightning is fixed, but its still a bit messed up/distorted as you can see here [link](https://s18.postimg.org/hzv9jgpd5/new.png) edit: it works great! thank you so much for your help! everything is perfect now